# What happens to the stack when moving a variable to an outer scope?

Tags: c++11, memory-management, stack, move-semantics

I think I understand how the stack works and what happens when a variable gets moved, but I can't find an answer to this question. Let me explain:

When a new scope is entered/created, a certain amount of memory is acquired on top of the stack. The stack pointer points to this memory. It represents the current size of the stack. When the scope is left, the memory is freed by having the stack pointer return to it's previous position.

Move semantics in C++11 or later move ownership of some data from one variable to another. This avoids copying data, because the memory holding the data stays the same. After the move, the moved-to variable points to the data's location in memory, and the moved-from variable basically becomes a null pointer. Here I might be making my first mistake, by relating move semantics to pointers too closely. Am I?

The actual question:
A variable is created in an inner scope and then moved to a variable in an outer scope. Then the inner scope exits. What happens to the stack?

Given the above, the stack pointer should return to it's previous position and free the inner scope memory. But it cannot do this, since the memory from the inner scope is still valid, since it's now attached to the outer scope variable. There might be a lot of memory blocked/wasted in between the outer (possibly global) scope and the formerly inner scope memory. This memory becomes available again once the outer scope exits. Until then, stack size is inflated. Is this true? Can this be avoided? Does the compiler prevent this?

Comment: "Move semantics" doesn't mean an object is physically moved to another location. It only means that the state managed by one object (e.g. a chunk of memory allocated on the heap, to which the object holds a pointer) is handed over to the other, in a manner specified by that object's class, which is often cheaper than making a full copy of that state. This does not in any way affect how memory occupied by these objects, whether on the stack or otherwise, is allocated or freed.

Comment: Exactly that is my point. The occupied memory remains the same after the move, but for the stack to function properly, all memory from a scope should be freed when the scope is left. Maybe I did not explain it clearly.

Comment: Move semantics are only useful for classes where you have a pointer to the heap (as far as you should care). Instead of a deep copy, you can safely shallow copy your class because you know your ownership of the heap data is yours alone, previous ownership was `move`d to you. So the memory you care about when `move`ing is never actually in the stack. You still copy your stack objects (class items with pointer to heap memory), but that is small and acceptable compared to a deep copy of all data in heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer, layman's terms, dodgy analogies and shaky c++ knowledge to follow...

I think I understand your confusion,

```
[stack frame a]
std::vector toPopulate;
    [stack frame b]
    std::vector toMove; // will be std::moved into `toPopulate` somehow
```

when the stack scope leaves `b` and goes back to `a`, how does the `move` ever prevent any copying, as you clearly cannot leave the memory in stack frame `b`...

Answer: It doesn't! the stack data for `toMove` is copied into `toPopulate`, `std::vector` doesn't store array its contents in the stack, it merely stores an address/pointer to where the memory is in the heap.

What `std::move` is doing here is saying to the `vector` don't deep copy yourself (don't copy the heap data into another place in the heap), just copy the `data` pointer, trust me, this is safe to do, safety is enforced at compile time.

So `toPopulate` is constructed, its dataCount and dataPointer and whatever else may be needed to describe a std::vector are written/copied into the heap memory but your heap data isn't touched, nor is it ever owned by multiple `std::vectors` in the stack, which would be troublesome indeed!

Comment: That makes sense and clears up another confusion of mine regarding the size of the stack... So the actual data I put into eg. an STL container is never stored on the stack? Only the let's call it metadata of a vector or a map is on the stack? That would be quickly copied and freed indeed. And would explain why I can store a vector tens or hundreds of MB in size on the stack. Is this correct?